# How to enable changes in AWX Containers?

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx, docker-ce

I am trying to install additional python packages in AWX container `awx_tasks` so that the changes could enable the ansible modules like `snow`, `ec2_elb_facts` run (which have pre-requisites as Python modules). I have made the changes in the container using:

```
# docker exec -it 80ab6bf562a9 bash
```

where `80ab6bf562a9` is the container id for `awx_task` container.

and then installed the required packages inside the custom virtual environment (as mentioned in the AWX [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/upgrade-migration-guide/virtualenv.html)). Post this, i have made the changes permanent by creating a new image with the container changes using:

```
# docker commit 80ab6bf562a9 ansible/awx_task:latest
```

Post this, ran the following command to map the new container with the newly created image with container changes.

```
# docker run --name awx_task -d 5290f9b3268c
```

Following are the containers post the above changes. Here, the newly created container which was mapped with the new image with changes in existing container is `968fb2a7da2f`.

```
# docker container ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                                                 NAMES
968fb2a7da2f        5290f9b3268c                 "/tini -- /bin/sh -c…"   2 days ago          Exited (143) 2 days ago                                                         awx_task
80ab6bf562a9        535bb2b8e1f3                 "/tini -- /bin/sh -c…"   3 weeks ago         Up 2 days                 8052/tcp                                              awx_task_OLD
aea2551951d5        b7c261b76010                 "/tini -- /bin/sh -c…"   3 weeks ago         Up 2 days                 0.0.0.0:80->8052/tcp                                  awx_web
e789a4a82a9e        memcached:alpine             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 weeks ago         Up 2 days                 11211/tcp                                             memcached
a8c74584255c        ansible/awx_rabbitmq:3.7.4   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 weeks ago         Up 2 days                 4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 15671-15672/tcp, 25672/tcp   rabbitmq
25f6f6ca7766        postgres:9.6                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 weeks ago         Up 2 days                 5432/tcp                                              postgres
```

Following are my images post above changes. Here, the newly created image (with changes) is `5290f9b3268c`.

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ansible/awx_task       latest              5290f9b3268c        2 days ago          1.48GB
postgres               9.6                 106bdfb062df        8 weeks ago         235MB
ansible/awx_task       <none>              535bb2b8e1f3        8 weeks ago         1.07GB
ansible/awx_web        <none>              b7c261b76010        8 weeks ago         1.04GB
hello-world            latest              2cb0d9787c4d        2 months ago        1.85kB
memcached              alpine              b40e8fa7e3e5        2 months ago        8.69MB
ansible/awx_rabbitmq   3.7.4               e08fe791079e        6 months ago        85.6MB
```

The new container is properly mapped with the new image (which has got the changes i wanted). The issue now is that when i stop the old container and start the new container AWX doesn't work. I can just view the UI, if i run any tasks like executing templates, it just freezes. It appears like the new container/images are not talking with the other containers like `awx_rabbitmq`, `postgres` etc. I have been reading multiple posts regarding this however, i couldn't find any single post which highlights anything regarding this.

I basically want the changes in the `awx_task` container to work so that i could achieve the goal of making the custom modules work. Could anyone suggest what can be done so that the new `awx_task` container could take the role of the older awx_task and AWX could work normally?

Comment: `docker exec`/`docker commit` isn't a best practice, in part because collaborators have no way of telling what went into your custom image.  Can you rewrite this as a Dockerfile, and if it's still a problem, add the Dockerfile to the question as a key part of a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i found the way to do this, i will share the steps to make the required changes.

The python package versions can be controlled from the `requirements` directory, AWX Task and AWX Web Images related changes can be applied in the `Dockerfile.j2` in the roles directory. Once the required changes are applied, we can run the setup using `ansible-playbook install.yml -i inventory`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the install.yml to restart the awx_task container, since it ensures the right environment variables are set, the right volumes are mapped, etc. Same command as you've used to install AWX: 
`ansible-playbook install.yml -i inventory`.
See [here](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/2.1.0/installer/roles/local_docker/tasks/standalone.yml#L122) for a full list of arguments that are used.